# How do I execute functions in a particular order when defined in a class?

Tags: python, function, numpy, class

I'm trying to build a function (defined inside a class) that calls on other functions (also defined in the class) in a particular order.

To be specific, I have created a class of image transformations (using `imgaug`), where all of the image augmentation parameters are passed as arguments in the constructor (see code below). I have then defined a couple of functions that take a raw image as an input, and apply the transformations thereon.

What I'd like to do is to be able to apply these transformation functions in a specific order. I think I'm close, but I keep getting the same errors. I'm using classes because I'd like to only have to specify the parameters once, and then use a list or tuple to specify the ordering of the functions, and ultimately have the option to make the ordering random.

**EDIT:** To add context to my question - the end goal here is to create a function that will randomly augment image data using various augmentation techniques applied in a random order, using random parameters (from within a specified range).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import imgaug as ia
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa

image = my_image_to_transform

class random_augmentation:
    
    def __init__(self,rotate_range=None,e_sev=None,):
        
        if rotate_range is None:
            self.rotate_range = None
        elif (type(rotate_range) is tuple) or (type(rotate_range) is list) and len(rotate_range) == 2:
            self.rotate_range = rotate_range
        else:
            self.rotate_range = None 
            
            
        if e_sev is None:
            self.e_sev = None
        else:
            self.e_sev = e_sev
        
        
    def aug_rotate(self,img):
        if self.rotate_range is not None:
            rotate = iaa.Affine(rotate=self.rotate_range)
            rotated_img = rotate(image=img)
            return rotated_img
        else:
            pass
    

    def aug_elastic(self,img):
        if self.e_sev is not None:
            elastic = iaa.imgcorruptlike.ElasticTransform(severity=self.e_sev)
            elastic_img = elastic(image=img)
            return elastic_img
        else:
            pass
        
    f_list = [aug_rotate,aug_elastic]
    
    def random_augment(img,order):
        for i in order:
            function = f_list[i]
            outp = function(img)
            img = outp
        return outp

r_aug = random_augmentation(rotate_range=(-30,30),e_sev=3)

augmented_img = r_aug.random_augment(image,[0,1])
```

The error I get is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-2a880e8381b8> in <module>
----> 1 augmented_img = r_aug.random_augment(image,[0,1])

TypeError: random_augment() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I'm not that experienced with classes, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong somewhere but for the life of me I can't figure it out!

Cheers!

**EDIT:** Typos

Comment: You are missing `self` as first argument for `random_augment`. Should be: `def random_augment(self, img, order):`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The trouble is, when I add the `self` argument I get other errors: first I get `NameError: name 'f_list' is not defined`, and then if I define `f_list` within the `random_augment` function, I get `NameError: name 'aug_rotate' is not defined`. So I'm not sure where to define what...

Comment: Move `f_list` into `random_augment` as `self.f_list ...` and make sure to use `self.f_list`everywhere.

Comment: I tried that too, but I still get the `NameError: name 'aug_rotate' is not defined` error I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I annotated the parts in the code where you should make the corrections suggested in the comments:

```py
import numpy as np
import imgaug as ia
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa

image = my_image_to_transform


class random_augmentation:

    def __init__(self, rotate_range=None, e_sev=None, ):

        if rotate_range is None:
            self.rotate_range = None
        elif (type(rotate_range) is tuple) or (type(rotate_range) is list) and len(rotate_range) == 2:
            self.rotate_range = rotate_range
        else:
            self.rotate_range = None

        if e_sev is None:
            self.e_sev = None
        else:
            self.e_sev = e_sev

        self.f_list = [self.aug_rotate, self.aug_elastic]  # Added self.f_list
        
    def aug_rotate(self, img):
        if self.rotate_range is not None:
            rotate = iaa.Affine(rotate=self.rotate_range)
            rotated_img = rotate(image=img)
            return rotated_img
        else:
            pass

    def aug_elastic(self, img):
        if self.e_sev is not None:
            elastic = iaa.imgcorruptlike.ElasticTransform(severity=self.e_sev)
            elastic_img = elastic(image=img)
            return elastic_img
        else:
            pass

    def random_augment(self, img, order):  # Added self
        for i in order:
            function = self.f_list[i]  # Use self.f_list
            outp = function(img)
            img = outp
        return outp


r_aug = random_augmentation(rotate_range=(-30, 30), e_sev=3)

augmented_img = r_aug.random_augment(image, [0, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def random_augment(self, img, order):
    for i in order:
        function = [self.aug_rotate, self.aug_elastic][i]
        outp = function(img)
    return outp
```